# Is it possible in Angular 13 to deploy build in different domain having different apiURL without rebuilding the application?

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic-programming

I am working on a functionality in which i will make a build for DEV environment and deploy on DEV domain . Further , without rebuilding the application again for QC environment , i want to make use of DEV build and deploy the same build on QC environment with different apiurl mentioned in environment files.

Step 1:- Made 2 environemnt files :- 1 for dev api url and 2nd for qcapiurl.

Step 2:- Made environmentService.ts file , code mentioned below:-

```
export class EnvironmentService {

  private currentEnvironment: any;

 

  constructor() {

    // Determine the current domain or environment and load the appropriate config

    const currentDomain = window.location.hostname;

 

    if (currentDomain === 'https://devums.sahibandhu.com') {

      this.currentEnvironment = environmentDev.baseUrlDev;

    }

    else if (currentDomain === 'https://qcums.sahibandhu.com') {

      this.currentEnvironment = environmentQc.baseUrlDev;

    }

    else if (currentDomain === 'https://uatums.sahibandhu.com') {

      this.currentEnvironment = environmentUat.baseUrlDev;

    }

    else if (currentDomain === 'https://ums.sahibandhu.com') {

      this.currentEnvironment = environmentProd.baseUrlDev;

    }

    else {

      // Default to a specific environment if none matches

      this.currentEnvironment = environmentDev.baseUrlDev;

      console.log(this.currentEnvironment);

    }

  }

 

  getConfig() {

    return this.currentEnvironment;

  }

}
```

Step 3:-
Register this service file in appmodule.ts file as

```
export function initializeApp(environmentService: EnvironmentService) {

  return () => environmentService.getConfig();

}
```

Step 4:- Fetch current environment variable during api call.

I was expecting that when i deploy dev build on QC environment the  it should automatically takes qcums.sahibandhu.com domain. But on qc and dev anv it is taking same apiurl i.e. devums.sahibandhu.com because i have made the build with devums.sahibandhu.com.

Comment: Do you use a cloud service (Azure/Amazon) and gitlab/github? The best and common way will using gitlab/gibhub and build pipelines which wanna do this for you. To set this in angular code itself is not so fine...

Comment: I use IIS Server to deploy angular application.

Comment: Is environmentDev.baseUrlDev devums.sahibandhu.com ?

Comment: environmentDev.baseUrlDev = 'https://devumsapi.sahibandhu.com';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got you!

When you are using: window.location.hostname

This property will return the DOMAIN of the URL.

In your cases will return:

For dev: devums.sahibandhu.com
For qc: qcums.sahibandhu.com
And so on.

You need to modify your if according to that. Example next:

```
const currentDomain = window.location.hostname;



if (currentDomain === 'devums.sahibandhu.com') {

  this.currentEnvironment = environmentDev.baseUrlDev;

}

else if (currentDomain === 'qcums.sahibandhu.com') {

  this.currentEnvironment = environmentQc.baseUrlDev;

}

else if (currentDomain === 'uatums.sahibandhu.com') {

  this.currentEnvironment = environmentUat.baseUrlDev;

}

else if (currentDomain === 'ums.sahibandhu.com') {

  this.currentEnvironment = environmentProd.baseUrlDev;

}

else {

  // Default to a specific environment if none matches

  this.currentEnvironment = environmentDev.baseUrlDev;

}
}
```

That is why you are always going to the else condition.

Comment: It worked ! Thankyou soo much for the solution . This is the first question i have asked on stack overflow and you provided instant solution . Again thankyou soo much for the support.